# How to use elevate zoom script in opencart 2.0.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add elevate zoom javascript into `opencart 2.0.1.1`. I used an extension which is [shown here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=10817&filter_search=zoom&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=39). But there is an issue in it that this works fine for the thumbnail image. When i click on addtional image the additional image should be open the thumbnail instead of the first image and zoom the function should be apply on it. Actually when I click on additional image it just open up in a popup.

Comment: this was just by mistake

Comment: That's fine - it just means you don't necessarily have the right people (i.e. the Javascript experts) looking at your question if it's not tagged with Javascript.

Comment: ya I am not a javascript expert

Comment: I am just using the opencart extension to use elevate zoom on my product image in the opencart 2.0.1.1 not the problem is that zoom is applied for the main image but when I click on an additional image it just open up in a pop up instead of replacing the main thumb image

Comment: I have used elevate jquery zoom script named jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min but now there is a problem that when I increase the thumb size of image from admin in opencart 2.0.1.1 the zoom function is not working properly as I have to do the thumb size 435px x 616px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a file in the extension that is jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min and here is an option to increase the width of zoomWindowContainer. So after increasing the thumbnail size you also have to increase the size of zoomWindowContainer.